# Leap year in FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, leap-year

Input - Year

Output - Leap year or not

I have tried

```
Program LeapYear;

var  
    Year:Integer

begin

    writeln('Insert year');
    readln(Year)

    if Year MOD 4 = 0 and Year MOD 100 = 0 and not Year MOD 400 = 0 then
        begin
            writeln(Year,'is leap year')
        end
    else
        begin
            writeln(Year,'is not leap year')
        end

end.
```

But this is not working

Comment: Grmpf. Can you pleas put it somehow formatted and as code? (Use newline at start of codeblock and then 4 blanks in front of ech code-line and then indent them correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. It should be:

```
if (year mod 400 = 0) or ((year mod 4 = 0) and not (year mod 100 = 0))
```

Comment: When I run the program it gives me Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"

Comment: I added some parentheses. Try again?

Answer (score 3):

The [`IsLeapYear`](http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/lazarus/fpc-lazarus-doc/rtl/sysutils/isleapyear.html) function is already defined in the `datih.inc` file, so you don't need write your own version, only you must add the `sysutils` unit.

Comment: But it is declared as word, so it does not work for years far in the future. Or negative years.

Comment: @BeniBela, do you think you'll ever need to determine if years after 65536 are leap :-) ? [+1]

Comment: @TLama: Yes, at the latest in 63524 years... And I needed to know it for negative years, so I have actually rewritten all date/time functions using integer (leap years are important, if you do not know the leap years you cannot do any date calculations)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```
if((a MOD 4) = 0) and ((a MOD 100) = 0) and ((a MOD 400) = 0) then y:=true 
else y:=false;
```

Comment: This logic is completely wrong, don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

`Program LeapYear`;

`Uses crt;`

```
var
```

`Year:Integer;`

```
 begin

clrscr;
  writeln('Insert year');
readln(Year);

if (Year MOD 4 = 0)then 
  writeln(Year,'is leap year');
If (Year Mod 4 >=1 ) Then 
  writeln(Year,'is not leap year')
```

end.

Comment: Not correct, 1900 and 2100 for example are not leap years.